# Signup form using Node.js and DynamoDB- Error: Cannot find module 'dynamodb-doc'\

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to create a signup page using node.js in DynamoDB Lambda. Any useful link and suggestions would be appreciated. Following is my code:

```
var doc= require('dynamodb-doc');
var dynamo = new doc.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    
    var email = event.email;
    
    var params = {
        "TableName" : "SignupsTable",
        "Item" : {
            "type": "email",
            "email": email,
            "date": new Date().toISOString()
        }
    };
    
    dynamo.putItem(params, function(err, data){
        console.log(err);
        console.log('Stored email' + email);
        context.succeed('Stored email: '+email);
    });
};
```

And the execution result is as follow:

Response:

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'dynamodb-doc'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",

  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'dynamodb-doc'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/task/index.js",
    "- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
    "- /var/runtime/index.js",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)",
    "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)",
    "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47"

  ]
}

Request ID:
"66c61f6c-de39-4e27-8fa0-89dca597b15b"
An unknown application error occurred
Runtime.ImportModuleError
```

Comment: Have you installed the npm module "dynamodb-doc"?

Comment: I am writing this code on AWS Lambda. So, do I need to install?

Comment: I believe yes, you will have to install it before deploying it